# JQuery Mobile select box not displaying selected value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectbox

I have a select box called **crop** and **variety**.The **variety** select box loaded via Ajax depends on the selection of **crop** and then rendered to JQueryMobile, the value populated correctly.but the selected value not displaying.

What could the reason?

my code:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#crop").change(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'GET',
                        url :'variety.php',
                        dataType:"json",
                        //data:"fname=me",
                        data: ({crop: $('#crop').val()}),
                        success : function(data){
                            //                        alert(data);
                            $("#variety").html(data);                               
                        },
                        error : function(data){
                            //                        alert("Error"+data);
                        }
                    });

                });
            });
        </script>
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="crop" class="select">Crop :</label>
                            <select name="crop" id="crop" data-native-menu="false"><option selected>Choose an option</option>
                                <?php
                                while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($tests)) {
                                    $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$res['id']}'>{$res['crop_name']}</option>";
                                }
                                echo $dropdown;
                                //}
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                            <label for="variety" class="select">Variety :</label>
                            <select name="variety" id="variety" data-placeholder="true">
                            </select>
                        </div>  
<?php
                    }
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call selectmenu('refresh'); on the element that contains the select menu.

$("#variety").html(data).selectmenu('refresh');

Should do it.  If not, try:

$("#variety").html(data).selectmenu('refresh', true);

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Almost the same issue tripped me up a few weeks ago, except it was with radio buttons.